# How to update field of a pointer to a struct in C?

Tags: c, struct, function-declaration, pointer-to-pointer

Im trying to update a field of a struct that's a pointer like so:

```
typedef struct Data *STRUCT_POINTER;
typedef struct Data
{
    int element;
    STRUCT_POINTER next;
} STRUCT_NODE;

 void manipulate(STRUCT_POINTER *data ) { 
        data->element = 1;
}
```

But I get a warning saying

```
expression must have pointer-to-struct-or-union type but it has type "STRUCT_POINTER *"
```

My question is, how how do I update the field element from the Data struct while using it as a pointer? Or is it even possible?

Answer (score 2):

The function parameter

```
void manipulate(STRUCT_POINTER *data ) { 
        data->element = 1;
}
```

has the type `struct Data **`. So dereferencing the pointer you again get a pointer of the type `struct Data *`.

You need to declare the function like

```
void manipulate(STRUCT_POINTER data ) { 
        data->element = 1;
        data->next = NULL;
}
```

Comment: Better yet, eliminate the pointer typedef and just use `STRUCT_NODE *`.  The bug was a direct result of hiding pointers in typedefs.